# Coin probability question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Question: Suppose that we flip a coin until either it comes up tails twice or we have flipped six times. What is the expected number of times we flip the coin?

I thought the answer was 4 because if it was a fair coin and we wanted tails to come out twice, we would flip it 4 times and it should come out twice as tails. But when I was trying to check the answer I found this: [luke's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586084/suppose-that-we-flip-a-coin-until-either-it-comes-up-tails-twice-or-we-have-flip)
. Here is the method that he used to get the answer:

```
P(N=2) = P(TT) = 1/4

P(N=3) = P(HTT , THT) = 2/8

P(N=4) = P(HHTT;HTHT;THHT) = 3/16

P(N=5) = 4/32

P(N=6) = 1 - 1/4 - 2/8 - 3/16 - 4/32 = 3/16

E(N) = 2x1/4 + 3x2/8 + 4x3/16 + 5x4/32 + 6x3/16 = 15/4 = 3.75
```

Why is this correct? For E(N), why are each of the probabilities multiplied by their respective N? (Why is 1/4 multiplied by 2?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *is* the mathematical definition of [Expected Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value). The expected value is the [weighted average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_average) - the tests where you toss 4 times have twice the weight of the tests where you toss twice.

Answer (score 1):

Expected value here is the expected number of flips.  You need to multiply the number of flips by the probability of that success across the space of possible successes.